# How to display validation errors in my website?

Tags: php, html, forms, validation

I just want this PHP code to display form validation errors in my website whenever someone uses the form incorrectly. Here is the code and I will also include the HTML of the form.

The code is only for reference, if you have a better way of doing it, then please show me.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    include_once 'dbh.inc.php';

    $first = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['first']);
    $last = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['last']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
    $number = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['number']);
    $uid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['uid']);
    $pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pwd']);

    // Error handlers
    // Check for empty fields

    if (empty($first) || empty($last) || empty($email) || empty($number) || empty($uid) || empty($pwd)) {
        header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=empty");
        exit(); 
    } else {
        // Check if input characters are valid
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z'-]+$/",$first) || !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z'-]+$/",$last)) {
            header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=invalid");
            exit(); 
        } else {
            // Check if email is valid
            if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=invalidemail");
                exit(); 
            } else {
                if (preg_match("/^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}$/", $number)) {
                    header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=invalidnumber");
                    exit();
            } else {
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_uid='$uid'";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                $resultcheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

                if ($resultcheck > 0) {
                    header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=usertaken");
                    exit(); 
                } else {
                   // Hashing the password
                    $hashedPwd = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                   // Insert the user into the database
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_first, user_last, user_email, user_number, user_uid, user_pwd) VALUES ('$first', '$last', '$email', '$number', '$uid', '$hashedPwd');";
                    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                    header("Location: ../accountcreated.php");
                    exit(); 

                }
            }
        }
    }

} else {
    header("Location: ../signup.php");
    exit();
}
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
<form class="memberform" action="includes/signup.inc.php" method="POST" novalidate>

                <input id="spfirst" class="form_fname" type="text" name="first" placeholder="First Name">
                <span class="error_form"></span>

                <input id="splast" class="form_lname" type="text" name="last" placeholder="Last Name">
                <span class="error_form"></span>

                <input class="form_email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail">
                <span class="error_form"></span>

                <input id="spnumber" class="form_tel" type="tel" name="number" placeholder="Phone number">
                <span class="error_form"></span>

                <input id="spuser" class="form_user" type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Username">
                <span class="error_form"></span>

                <input class="form_password" type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
                <span class="error_form"></span>

                <button type="submit" name="submit">Create Account</button>

                  </form>
```

Okay there it is. I already tried so many things a nothing seems to work... Maybe it's due to my limited knowledge with PHP.

Comment: php errors or form validation errors?

Comment: form validation errors

Comment: You can download a browser extension like firephp (firebug). Then activate the developer tools in the browser. Every time you charge, refresh or send information (post, get) this extension will "debug" your code and if it has any error. It will show it to you in the developer tools window

Comment: I'm trying to display PHP form validation errors, not bugs.. I just edited the question

Comment: Since this is a post form, I would recommend you do things another way: re-render the page inside the post operation if you get a validation failure, and do a Location redirect if you succeed. In the case of the failure, you will have all the failure tests to hand already, which means that you can render as many validation failures as you like (it is common to show all failures rather than one at a time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the best way to do it in my opinion, but following your current code, I suggest you do this.

In your `signup.php` file, add this where you want the error message to appear (within the HTML if you want):

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['signup'])){
    switch($_GET['signup']){
        case 'empty':
            $msg = 'Empty fields';
            break;
        case 'invalid':
            $msg = 'Invalid input';
            break;
        case 'invalidemail':
            $msg = 'Invalid email';
            break;
        case 'invalidnumber':
            $msg = 'Invalid number';
            break;
        case 'usertaken':
            $msg = 'User taken';
            break;
        default:
            $msg = ''; // Default message, if any
            break;
    }
    echo '<div class="error_div">'.$msg.'</div>'; // here's where the message appears
}
?>
```

That will show your messages. Obviously, feel free to change the class name and style it as you wish.

Or you can simply do something like this (changing the text and stuff depending on the result you're looking for):

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['signup'])){
    if($_GET['signup'] == 'empty'){
        echo '<span class="error_form">Empty values</span>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: And by the way, your code looks very familiar, someone else recently asked a question that had a similar code. Are you following a tutorial? This other person had almost the same question at some point.

Comment: Thank you so much! And is there a way to show the errors beside each input?

Comment: Yes, there is. You should change the `switch()` statement for an `if-else` statement. This way, wherever you want the specific error to be shown, you can simply check for that one alone. I'll update the answer to do that!

Comment: Thank you! And if you know of any other better way to do the php form validators could you please show me.. I'm not looking to use my code. I just posted it as a reference. So if there is any other way to do it that is simpler, please show me :)

Comment: Actually, before I update the answer... and also because you say that your current code is just a reference... how exactly do you want it to be? Because you're checking for empty values but never exactly asking which ones. You're just checking if at least one is empty, so there's no way right now to tell which `<input>`s are missing and which are not. Also, I speak Italian, we can later open a chat to continue the discussion on how to make it "better", which might change the entire way you're working, so that's why I prefer not to talk about it right here.

Comment: Let's do that then! Let's open a chat so I can explain everything

Comment: Just did. Inviami un messaggio cosi ti aggiungo pure

Answer (score 0):

Since you're redirecting users to the signup page with a specific error message (Example: usertaken), you can use `$_GET` to handle the errors.

So in your signup page, do this

```
$error should = "" ;
if(isset($_GET['signup'])) {
    $error = $_GET['signup'];
    if(!empty($error){
        //check for specific errors
        if($error == "usertaken"){
             $errorMsg = "The username has already been taken, try again";
        } 
    } 
}
```

You can use the `$errorMsg` in your HTML  and put it where you want to display the error and design it accordingly.

NOTE: I have not done any sanitization, trying to keep this short.

Comment: Thank you! What is the best way to do it? I just followed a tutorial so I'm not sure which way is better.  If you could help me change the code to make simpler or less complicated, it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I have edited the answer to allow you to use the error messages and display them where you want

Comment: Please do not mention "I'm on my mobile" in answers. We try to use a technical standard of writing here. If you really need to notify someone of this fact, put it in the comments instead.